# In express how do I redirect a user to an external url?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a payment system using node.js and braintree, when the payment is successful I want to send the user to the back end. My back end is setup elsewhere.

I have tried

```
res.writeHead(301,
  {Location: 'http://app.example.io'}
);
res.end();
```

So window.location is obviously not available. I cant think of any ways to redirect a user?

Comment: `window.location` why is it unavailable?

Comment: @Esqarrouth window.location is available because you are in a NodeJS scope, not in the browser scope.

Comment: :point_up: I think he means "unavailable"

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You can do

```
res.redirect('https://app.example.io');
```

Express docs: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: I tried that earlier but I dont think it worked trying it again.

Comment: I just tested it on a personal app and it redirects correctly. Question: What version of express are you using?

Comment: Well if your willing to link your github repo I can try to debug more, but to answer your question... this is how you redirect to an external site in express.

Comment: Yeah I would agree, it's weird, I am sure I am overlooking something. On success I will just render a success message and give the user the option to go to the backend.

Comment: how to pass headers to this redirect url?

Comment: Headers can't be passed to redirect

Answer (score 28):

The selected answer did not work for me. It was redirecting me to: `locahost:8080/www.google.com` - which is nonsense.

[301 Moved Permanently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) needs to be included with `res.status(301)` as seen below.

```
app.get("/where", (req, res) => {

    res.status(301).redirect("https://www.google.com")

})
```

You are in the same situation since your back-end is elsewhere.

Comment: I was having similar issues and I found that this has to do with `https://` or `http://` needing to be attached to the redirect url. If not it seems to fail. Also adding a `301` results in the redirect url being cached by the browser which means everytime you hit the same url it will redirect you to the first address regardless of whether it could have changed or not.

Answer (score 11):

```
    app.get("/where", (req, res) => {

    res.status(301).redirect("https://www.google.com")

})
```

You need to include the status (301)

Answer (score 2):

I just have the same issue and got it work by adding "next". I use routers so maybe you have same issue as mine? Without next, i got error about no render engine...weird

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var debug = require('debug')('node_blog:server');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  debug("index debug");
  res.render('index.html', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
    //var pass = req.body("password");
    //var loginx = req.body("login");
    //res.render('index.html', { title: 'Express' });
    res.redirect("/users")
    next
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nobody mentioned this different way of redirect as an answer here, so I write it:

- To **permanent redirect**:

  ```
  res.redirect(301, 'http://app.example.io');
  ```
- To **temporary redirect**:

  ```
  res.redirect(302, 'http://app.example.io');
  // OR
  res.redirect('http://app.example.io');
  ```

Answer (score -12):

None of these worked for me, so I tricked the receiving client with the following result:

```
res.status(200).send('<script>window.location.href="https://your external ref"</script>');
```

Some will say if noscript is on this does not work, but really which site does not use it.

Comment: Please be so kind and elaborate a bit what you mean by *tricked*.

Comment: Rather than the server returning a 301 to tell the browser to immediately redirect, they are returning a webpage with JavaScript that redirects the url.