# Forward post request to another server and capture response

Tags: node.js, express

```js
app.post("/test", async function(req, res) {
    //resp = forward_to("127.0.0.1:1024", req)
}
```

How would you do the commented line considering that this post may contain a body of multipart or url encoded ect.

Comment: Please perform bare-minimum-effort research before posting here, as Stack Overflow doesn't accept duplicative questions. Please also familiarize yourself with the guideliens on [ask]. This is a duplicate of [Node.js/Express.js forward POST request to another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603776/node-js-express-js-forward-post-request-to-another-domain)

Comment: @esqew first of all why do you assume that, second of all it does not solve anything because the solution does not even run.