# How to send a post request on node js without there being a page redirect or form refresh. there is no preventdefault

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have an HTML form which hits this endpoint. It sends data, but I don't want the page to refresh once sending the data. is this possible?

im not sure what the best solution is, there is no preventdefault in nodejs, but I don't want to redirect/refresh the same page

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.static("public"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("index.html", { root: __dirname });
});

app.post("/rumi", (req, res) => {
  console.log(res.req.body);

  res.json({ status: "ok" });


});

app.get("/rumi", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("index2.html", { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Here is the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Drawing Tools</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    #map,
    html,
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #panel {
      width: 200px;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 13px;
      float: right;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    #color-palette {
      clear: both;
    }

    .color-button {
      width: 14px;
      height: 14px;
      font-size: 0;
      margin: 2px;
      float: left;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    #delete-button {
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="/js/script.js"></script>

  <script>
    function submitRumiForm(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("rumiForm"));
      var options = {
        body: formData,
        method: "POST"
      }
      fetch("/rumi", options).then(function(data) {
        console.log("post successful");
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      })
    }

    var el = document.getElementById("stair-button")
    if (el) {
      el.addEventListener("click", submitRumiForm);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="panel">
    <div id="color-palette"></div>
    <div>
      <button id="delete-button">Delete Selected Shape</button>
      <button id="delete-all-button">Delete All Shapes</button>
    </div>
    <form id="rumiForm"
          action="/rumi"
          method="POST">
      <div>
        <h3>Elements</h3>
      </div>
      <button type="submit"
              name="stairs"
              value="clicked"
              id="stair-button"
              onclick="console.log('hi')">
        <img src="./images/stair.png" />
      </button>
      <button type="submit"
              name="ramp"
              value="clicked"
              id="ramp-button">
        <img src="./images/ramp.png" />
      </button>
      <button type="submit"
              name="exit"
              value="clicked"
              id="exit-button"><img src="./images/exit.png" /></button>
      <button type="submit"
              name="narrow"
              value="clicked"
              id="narrow-button">
        <img src="./images/narrow.png" />
      </button>
      <button type="submit"
              name="wide"
              value="clicked"
              id="wide-button"><img src="./images/wide.png" /></button>
      <button type="submit"
              name="construction"
              value="clicked"
              id="construction-button">
        <img src="./images/construction.png" />
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have an HTML form which hits this endpoint. It sends data, but I don't want the page to refresh once sending the data. is this possible?

im not sure what the best solution is, there is no preventdefault in nodejs, but I don't want to redirect/refresh the same page

[This happens when i tried the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebwl6.png)

[This happens after a while](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2jGJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

As this is browser specific behaviour, this has to be done on the client side via JavaScript & using prevent default with the form, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454310/stop-form-refreshing-page-on-submit).

If you simply don't want to refresh to that specific page, you can do a redirect in express, so after they submit the form, they are directed away from it, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352871/in-express-how-do-i-redirect-a-user-to-an-external-url).

Comment: I tried doing it from the client side but I still get the error of the pic i inserted @mjr

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the page to reload, then you need to send the POST with Javascript from the browser using an Ajax call rather than letting the browser post the form automaticallyl.  Anytime the browser posts the form automatically, it will display the form response in the browser window.  So, if you don't want that, you have to take control (in the browser) and submit the form with your own Javascript so then you can control what happens with the result.

Add an identifier to your form:

```
<form id="rumiForm" action="/rumi" method="POST">
```

Add this script **after the form in your HTML**:

```
<script>

function submitRumiForm(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("rumiForm"));
   var options = {body: formData, method: "POST"}
   fetch("/rumi", options).then(function(response) {
       return response.json();
   }).then(function(data) {
       // have the JSON response from the POST operation here
       console.log(data);
   }).catch(function(err) {
       console.log(err);
   })
}

document.getElementById("stair-button").addEventListener("click", submitRumiForm);

</script>
```

Change this form item from this:

```
  <button type="submit"
          name="stairs"
          value="clicked"
          id="stair-button"
          onclick="console.log('hi')">
```

to this:

```
  <button type="submit"
          name="stairs"
          value="clicked"
          id="stair-button"
  >
```

Comment: i tried your solution but look at the picture i attached, thats what happened

Comment: @HusseinNagri - I have made some edits to the solution in my answer, but what you show in your screenshot is a server-side problem.  Not sure what to do with that.

Comment: your code worked, but the post request still times out after a bit, is there a reason why? I added another pic

Comment: @HusseinNagri - You need to send a response of some kind on the server - otherwise the browser is still waiting for a response from the ajax call.  If you don't have anything particular to send, the just do `res.json({status: "ok"});`.  I don't know what `res.off()` is or what you intended with that.  I don't see that as an Express method.  I would replace that with something like `res.json({status: "ok"});`.

Comment: the issue when i do ```res.json({status: "ok"});``` is that the page will be now show that

Comment: @HusseinNagri - well you need the preventDefault.

Comment: yeah thats added in as well, i can re update the code for you

Comment: @HusseinNagri - You have to put the `<script>` I asked you to add AFTER the form HTML.  The form doesn't exist at the point you're trying to hook up to it so it never gets hooked up.  Put the `<script>` right before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: That works, but the response doesnt return anything unfortunately

Comment: @HusseinNagri - OK, progress.  See how I edited the client-side `fetch()` call to actually read the JSON response.  Feel free to examine [some doc for `fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) at any time to learn how it works.

Comment: ```   var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("rumiForm"));
``` what does this do? i dont think this seems to be getting any data

Comment: hey man, do you think you can explain the script more. i dont think it's sending anything to /rumi

Comment: @HusseinNagri - The latest code you show in your question, has the `<script>` tag in the wrong place.  It needs to be right before the `</body>` tag or it can't hook up to your form.  You should be able to use `console.log()` statements in both your client code and your server code to see EXACTLY what is happening in the code.  I cannot do that since I don't have your working server.

Comment: @HusseinNagri - `var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("rumiForm"))` gets the data out of the form and puts it into a `FormData` object.   In [this reference page on fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), search for `const form = new FormData(document.getElementById('login-form'));` and you will see an identical example to what I suggested your code do (obviously the form id and URL are different, but otherwise the `fetch()` arguments are identical.