# How to redirect to a URL in loopback 4

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, loopback, loopback4

I am Using this code.

```
import { RestApplication } from '@loopback/rest';
    const app = new RestApplication();
          app.redirect('', 'https://www.google.com/');
```

When i call API it's showing `204 response` code but not redirecting to this URL. I'm using loopback4

Answer (score 4):

Same way you do with `express`. Just do it in `controller`.

```
  @get('redirect')
  async redirect(@inject(RestBindings.Http.RESPONSE) response: Response) {
    response.redirect('https://www.google.com');
  }
```

See similar solution with `express` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28353428/11883937)

***PS:***

you **must** import `Response` from `loopback/rest` to work this solution

```
import {Response} from '@loopback/rest'
```

---

**Edit after comment**

Also you can do it with sequences. Check it [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Routes.html#implementing-http-redirects) on documentation example.

All above methods are tested on `loopback4`

Comment: Hi @Salitha , thanks for answer. it's not working when i have used  import {Response} from '@loopback/rest', i have got error  ReferenceError: Response is not defined. Response.redirect('https://www.google.com') this is my code

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer with two examples. Try them.

Comment: Also, check this [git issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1881) . It may help. BTW, what is your loopback 4 version?