# Change Browser URL after Authentication using Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am using **express** as my middleware and have the browser **URL** as **http://sampleDomain/AUTH/login** and after successful login I would like to show the **URL** as **http://sampleDomain/**

```
app.use('/AUTH',authHelper)
app.use('/*',helper)
```

initially if User not logged in then map to authHelper and once if the credentials entered by user are valid then I need to change the browser URL from **http://sampleDomain/AUTH/login** to **http://sampleDomain/**
so that **app.use('/*',helper)** can be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In express how do I redirect a user to an external url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352871/in-express-how-do-i-redirect-a-user-to-an-external-url)

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `res.redirect()` would do the job.